# Granting "Create Directory" Privileges in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I want to run a `CREATE DIRECTORY` query in Oracle 10, but it's giving me an insufficient privileges error.

Can anybody tell me how to grant this privilege to my user through the system as a user?

Answer (score 19):

From the [Oracle 10gR2 documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5007.htm#i2061958):

> You must have CREATE ANY DIRECTORY system privilege to create directories.

You would use the following command to grant the privilege to the schema that will create the directory:

```
SQL> GRANT CREATE ANY DIRECTORY TO vnz;

Grant succeeded
```

As always with the privileges `ANY`, be careful who you will grant them to. It is indeed a powerful privilege best left to DBAs.

Comment: This is a VERY dangerous privilege as it can make any OS directory on the server visible to Oracle via PL/SQL. This includes the Oracle installation directory itself plus the data files....

Comment: how to revert this grant?

Comment: @SandunChathuranga Use the [`REVOKE`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9021.htm#SQLRF01609) command.

Comment: @VincentMalgrat Would you mind checking my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44142383/oracle-how-to-grant-create-any-directory-with-the-restriction-that-all-directori) on whether or not it is possible to restrict the creation of directories to within a given directory?

Comment: @MatthewMoisen I don't think it's possible to restrict the `CREATE ANY` privilege. Maybe you could create a procedure / package in a schema with this privilege that would create a directory while enforcing the subdirectory rule. This package would create the directory and grant rights on it to the current user. You would grant the `EXECUTE` privilege on this package to the user.

Comment: As usual Oracle privileges are a big pain in the ass. I'm having to use this to see what tables are in a backup.

Answer (score 4):

From Oracle docs:

"You must have CREATE ANY DIRECTORY system privilege to create directories."

So,

grant create any directory to userOfInterest;