# Not getting grant access in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, permissions

I was facing the problem of "insufficient privilege" while I tried to create a directory in oracle,  so I followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058756/granting-create-directory-privileges-in-oracle) but , now I am getting the same error and cannot grant the user - "forum" the permission to create directory.How to solve this?
[image]

Comment: Which user are you connected as when you run that grant statement? You need to be a privileged user - the forum user can't grant that privilege to itself, for instance.

Comment: I have connected as "SYS" as sysdba