# Oracle How to grant CREATE ANY DIRECTORY with the restriction that all directories must be created inside a given directory?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

I want to grant the `CREATE ANY DIRECTORY` permission to a user, with the following restriction: all directories created by this user must be inside of `/foo/bar`, and any attempt to create a directory outside of this should fail with a permission error. How may I do this on Oracle 11G or 12C?

Comment: This restriction needs to be enforced by means of an OS Oracle is installed on. Directory object is a logical structure. A user can provide an absolutely arbitrary  string literal as a directory path when creating an object - there is no validation. If you insist on enforcing this restriction by means of Oracle, then system level trigger is your only choice. But, you would need to not forget it exists and recompile it every time directory changes or delete/disable it when you do not need it anymore.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov When a schema with `CREATE ANY DIRECTORY` privilege executes a `CREATE DIRECTORY`, which OS user gets ownership of the directory? I'm currently developing on my Windows and don't have a linux available to test it out, but I presume that the OS user is the user that the Oracle instance runs under. If that is true, then wouldn't it be a security concern to grant this privilege to a schema as they would be able to read/write any directory to which the Oracle user has access to?

Comment: CREATE DIRECTORY creates **oracle** directories, not OS directories.  For clarification: select * from dba_directories;  You can create any oracle directory you want... which may or may not actually reference an OS directory at all (since the check for OS directory exists doesn't happen when the oracle directory object is created, but happen when the directory object is actually used: e.g. from utl_file commands).

Comment: Yes it's the OS user the Oracle instance runs under. And yes, this presents a potential risk. That's why `create any directory` and `read/write/execute` privileges  should not be granted left and right. Only `SYSDBA` or a `DBA` user should have them for a period of time need for him/her to complete a task. In 12c there is a parameter called `PDB_OS_CREDENTIAL` (I personally haven't tested it yet) which allows to use different OS users for PDBs.

Comment: The only option is to create a procedure doing this (including the path check) and then grant user to execute this procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends, if you want to restrict which OS directories Oracle can access from utl_file commands, you can set the `utl_file_dir` parameter.  Unfortunately, this parameter is system wide, so you won't be able to grant/revoke for a specific user using this parameter.  Also keep in mind that if you make changes to this parameter, those changes won't go into effect until the Oracle database is restarted:

```
alter system set utl_file_dir = '/foo/bar' scope=spfile;
shutdown immediate;
startup open;
```

Consult the [12.1 Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-DCA8A942-ACE1-46D6-876E-3244F390BCAE.htm#REFRN10230) for more information regarding `utl_file_dir`.

That said, if you really want to restrict who can create Oracle Directories to specific OS directories, a procedure would be appropriate for that task since that would allow you to have finer grained control (and limit who has the very powerful `create any directory` privilege to the owner of the procedure):

```
sqlplus kjohnston

create or replace procedure mydircreate (p_dir varchar2)
as
  ex_custom EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT( ex_custom, -20001 );
begin
  if lower(p_dir) not like '/foo/bar/%' then
    raise_application_error( -20001, 'Not authorized' );
  end if;

  execute immediate 'create or replace directory mydir as ''' || p_dir || '''';
end mydircreate;

create user testuser identified by <password>;
grant create session to testuser;
grant execute on kjohnston.mydircreate to testuser;

exit;

sqlplus testuser

SQL> exec kjohnston.mydircreate('mydir', '/randomdir');
ORA-20001: Not authorized

SQL> exec kjohnston.mydircreate('mydir', '/foo/bar/baz');
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can include this restriction in trigger. List of system events and attributes [Working with system events](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_ev.htm)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_before_ddl 
BEFORE DDL ON DATABASE
declare 
    v_sql ORA_NAME_LIST_T;
   v_ddl varchar2(4000);
   v_cnt BINARY_INTEGER;
   is_valid number;
begin
   if  ora_sysevent in ('CREATE') and ora_dict_obj_type = 'DIRECTORY' then 
       v_cnt := ora_sql_txt (v_sql);
       FOR i IN 1..v_cnt LOOP     
          v_ddl := v_ddl || RTRIM (v_sql (i), CHR (0));
       END LOOP;
       v_ddl :=  regexp_substr(v_ddl,'AS ''(.*)''', 1, 1, 'i', 1 ); -- get path from ddl_statement             
       -- check valid directory here, path is in v_ddl ;
       is_valid := REGEXP_instr(v_ddl,'^/valid_dir/.*$');
       if (is_valid = 0) then 
         raise_application_error(-20000,'Directory is not valid' || v_ddl);
       end if; 
   end if;   
END;
/

CREATE DIRECTORY valid_dir AS '/valid_dir/xyz';

CREATE DIRECTORY invalid_dir AS '/invalid_dir/xyz';
```